# upstream prematurely closed connection uwsgi nginx

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

Good afternoon, colleagues.

help with the solution of the problem (maybe even 2:))))

nginx sends a mistake, though not always, and every 2-5 minutes
tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
2015/03/29 12:15:28 [error] 22735#0: *219816 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 213.ххх.ххх.180, server: ххх, request: "POST /?uuid=a_4526e8e2-e0ac-426e-ac95-7a0c8ac37cc1 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///home/uwsgi-home/parsecdr/uwsgi.sock:", host: ххх
```

in logs uwsgi usually quiet and calm, but sometimes it bug

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/uwsgi-home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/uwsgi-home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 199, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/uwsgi-home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 236, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/home/uwsgi-home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 91, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "/home/uwsgi-home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 350, in get_traceback_html
    return t.render(c)
  File "/home/uwsgi-home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 148, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/uwsgi-home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 142, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/uwsgi-home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 848, in render
    return mark_safe(''.join(bits))
MemoryError
```

This error is the same error nginx as it happens and not (probably two different problems)

Code - the parser xml. Files and benevolent 20-40 KB.
The project is only one views and one URL.

Most likely a problem with nginx or uwsgi confs

Ask to see and tell. Actually configs:

```
[uwsgi]
# Django-related settings
# the base directory (full path)
chdir           = /home/uwsgi-home/parsecdr/
# Django's wsgi file
module          = parsecdr.wsgi
module          = parsecdr.wsgi:application
module          = django.core.wsgi:get_wsgi_application()
plugins         = python
# the virtualenv (full path)
home            = /home/uwsgi-home

# process-related settings
# master
master          = true
# maximum number of worker processes
processes       = 10
limit-as        = 192
max-requests    = 5000
harakiri    = 120
buffer-size     = 49152
# the socket (use the full path to be safe
socket          = /home/uwsgi-home/parsecdr/uwsgi.sock
# ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
#chmod-socket    = 666
# clear environment on exit
vacuum          = true
touch-reload    = /home/uwsgi-home/parsecdr/touch-reload
daemonize       = /var/log/uwsgi/parsecdr.log
```

и nginx
    upstream parsecdr {
        server unix:///home/uwsgi-home/parsecdr/uwsgi.sock; # for a file socket
    }

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name parsecdr.rt.ru;
    charset     utf-8;

    large_client_header_buffers 8 48k;
    client_max_body_size 50M;
    keepalive_timeout 75s;
    proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
    proxy_read_timeout 60s;


    location / {
        proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
        proxy_send_timeout   600s;
        proxy_read_timeout   600s;
        proxy_buffer_size    64k;
        proxy_buffers     16 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;


        uwsgi_pass  parsecdr;
        include     /home/uwsgi-home/parsecdr/uwsgi.params;
    }
}
```

Again, the error appears periodically.
For every 50-60 records one error.
And the second test may pass without errors

Update:
URL:

```
url(r'^$', xv.parse),
```

View:

```
def parse(request):
    import urllib
    cdr_file = request.POST.get('cdr')
    cdr_file = urllib.unquote(cdr_file)

    cdr = XML_CDR()
    cdr.fs_host = request.META["REMOTE_ADDR"]
    cdr.parse_from_str(cdr_file)
    return HttpResponse(status=201)
```

Comment: Your Django stacktrace says "MemoryError" -- are you sure the problem is not with your Django project having some problems with memory? Did you debug that part?

Comment: Current host is vm on vmware. Another host have this error

Comment: Sorry, how to enable debug?

Comment: it looks like Django is raising exceptions in the traceback. So you may want to try testing different URLs in your project -- some with simple response containing a small HTML page. If you're getting these errors because the response is too large, then that may cause a memory error. This is my guess. It doesn't look like an nignx or uwsgi problem -- if you are getting errors from Django.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the nginx logs? Uwsgi usualy outputs a lot of diagnostic information in the log. Do you see anything that looks like an error?

Comment: I see MemoryError in uwsgi.log I try 10K get some url from server (simple html page)

Comment: It may be that some of your response content is too big. What are you returning from your Django view?

Comment: I just reread your nginx error message. Are you getting the disconnection error when you are using POST? or are you getting the error during GET?

Comment: In my view only post

Comment: I'm not sure what could be the problem. I would suggest trying to test proxy buffering parameters -- trying turning it off, then test, then try increasing proxy buffer size. If your view is returning a response with a large body that may be the problem. Also, I would try using a different wsgi server to see if you enounter the same problem -- maybe gunicorn or another wsgi server like the cherrypy wsgi server just to test and debug .

Comment: The MemoryError from the Django traceback may or may not have to do with your problem. I think it's saying that it ran out of memory while trying to render the html or stackframe information to display the trackback. If you have a low-memory VM or server this could happen.

Comment: Test server have 2Gb, and only 1.3 is used.

Comment: Based on the Django traceback, the exception is raised in django/core/handlers/base.py's "get_response" method and it probably has something to do with what your view is generating (the exception is not specified). You might want to set up a debug log in your view to write info as you are processing the data, then see if something is triggering the  Django exception.

Comment: I copied the project to another host (also on this virtual physical host).
Reduce the number of processors to one.
Launched in 5 streams parsing.

No errors found.

Django (1.7.1) - host for testing
nginx 1.2.1-2.2 + wheezy3

Django (1.7.5) - the current host
nginx 1.2.1-2.2 + wheezy3

On a test version ovsgi hochte can not say.

Right now installed a new host, check that there will be)

Comment: This issue in the Django bug tracker is related to the error you are getting with the MemoryError -- it is caused by get_response running out of memory while trying to render the traceback: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20368 -- it does not tell you what your error is but it may indicate that the exception being raised is related to your view's response content.

Comment: I updated to the current version of Django (including all software). Until the error is not visible.